# FileSystemWatcher Not Triggering Events in Windows Service Created with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

Trying to create a Windows service using VB.NET which will watch for changes in a folder using FileSystemWatcher. Service installs and starts fine but doesn't trigger any events when I add or delete a file.

The "started watcher" comment appears in the event log but I get no other event log entries.

I've researched other examples using FSW (in both VB and C#) and can't figure out what's wrong. I had the FSW details in a different class but pulled it all into one class and reduced the code as much as possible to troubleshoot. Still nothing when I create or delete a file in the watched folder.

Could it be a permissions thing? What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class TestFileWatcher

    Dim WithEvents watcher As System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    Dim myLog As System.Diagnostics.EventLog
    Dim folderName As String
    Dim fileTypes As String

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
        ' in motion so your service can do its work.
        myLog = New System.Diagnostics.EventLog()
        If Not EventLog.SourceExists("My Test Log") Then
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("My Test Log", "Application")
        End If
        myLog.Source = "My Test Log"
        folderName = "C:\temp\"
        fileTypes = "*.*"
        Try
            watcher = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()
            DefineWatcher()
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
            myLog.WriteEntry("started watcher")
        Catch
            ErrorHandler(e)
            System.Environment.Exit(-1)     '0=successful exit
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
        StopWatcher()
    End Sub

    Public Sub StopWatcher()
        watcher.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Public Sub RecordOnEventLog(ByVal str As String)
        myLog.WriteEntry(str)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ErrorHandler(ByVal e As ApplicationException)
        Dim err As String
        err = "ERROR" + vbCrLf
        err += "Message: " + e.Message + vbCrLf
        err += "Source: " + e.Source + vbCrLf
        err += "Method: " + e.TargetSite.Name + vbCrLf
        err += "Stack Trace: " + e.StackTrace + vbCrLf
        err += "Error String: " + e.ToString + vbCrLf
        err += "Application shut down at " & My.Computer.Clock.GmtTime.ToString
        myLog.WriteEntry(err)
    End Sub

    Public Sub DefineWatcher()
        watcher.BeginInit()
        watcher.Path = folderName
        watcher.Filter = fileTypes
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = False
        watcher.NotifyFilter = System.IO.NotifyFilters.FileName
        watcher.NotifyFilter = watcher.NotifyFilter Or System.IO.NotifyFilters.Attributes
        watcher.NotifyFilter = watcher.NotifyFilter Or System.IO.NotifyFilters.CreationTime
        watcher.NotifyFilter = watcher.NotifyFilter Or System.IO.NotifyFilters.Security
        AddHandler watcher.Created, AddressOf OnCreated
        AddHandler watcher.Deleted, AddressOf OnDeleted
        watcher.EndInit()
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnCreated(src As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
        RecordOnEventLog("New file added to temp folder, path: " + e.FullPath)
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnDeleted(src As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
        RecordOnEventLog("Item deleted")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Note that AFAIK you don't need to declare the variable `WithEvents` if you are adding handlers manually, it would be useful if you were using `Handles` on the handler routines instead of adding them with `AddHandler`.  Make sure you have `Option Strict On` to catch any issues with type (and signature) mismatches.  (I don't think either is the root cause of your problems, though I can't 100% rule it out.)

Comment: First things first: does the code produce the desired results (Event Log entry), if you run it as a standard Win/Console application?

Comment: @Craig Thank you. Not sure what fixed it but added `Option Strict On`, removed the `WithEvents`, corrected a type conversion in the error handling (`Exception` and `ApplicationException`) and now it's working!  @hel-oween Tried testing as a console application but once it's set up as a Windows Service it wouldn't let me change it to a console application without modifying the code `OnStart` funcitons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the help.
Not sure what was preventing it from working earlier but it is now working. Here is working code for anyone interested.

```
Option Strict On

Imports System.IO

Public Class TestFileWatcher

    Dim watcher As System.IO.FileSystemWatcher = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()
    Dim myLog As System.Diagnostics.EventLog = New System.Diagnostics.EventLog()
    Dim folderName As String = "C:\temp"
    Dim fileTypes As String = "*.*"
    Dim myLogName As String = "My Test Log"

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        StartLog()
        Try
            DefineWatcher()
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
            myLog.WriteEntry("started watcher hopefully")
        Catch e As Exception
            ErrorHandler(e)
            System.Environment.Exit(-1)     '0=successful exit
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        StopWatcher()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartLog()
        If Not EventLog.SourceExists(myLogName) Then
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(myLogName, "Application")
        End If
        myLog.Source = myLogName
    End Sub

    Private Sub StopWatcher()
        watcher.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub RecordOnEventLog(ByVal str As String)
        myLog.WriteEntry(str)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ErrorHandler(ByVal e As Exception)
        Dim err As String
        err = "ERROR" + vbCrLf
        err += "Message: " + e.Message + vbCrLf
        err += "Source: " + e.Source + vbCrLf
        err += "Method: " + e.TargetSite.Name + vbCrLf
        err += "Stack Trace: " + e.StackTrace + vbCrLf
        err += "Error String: " + e.ToString + vbCrLf
        err += "Application shut down at " & My.Computer.Clock.GmtTime.ToString
        myLog.WriteEntry(err)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DefineWatcher()
        watcher.BeginInit()
        watcher.Path = folderName
        watcher.Filter = fileTypes
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = False
        watcher.NotifyFilter = System.IO.NotifyFilters.FileName
        watcher.NotifyFilter = watcher.NotifyFilter Or System.IO.NotifyFilters.Attributes
        watcher.NotifyFilter = watcher.NotifyFilter Or System.IO.NotifyFilters.CreationTime
        watcher.NotifyFilter = watcher.NotifyFilter Or System.IO.NotifyFilters.Security
        AddHandler watcher.Created, AddressOf OnCreated
        AddHandler watcher.Deleted, AddressOf OnDeleted
        watcher.EndInit()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnCreated(src As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
        RecordOnEventLog("New file added to temp folder, path: " + e.FullPath)
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnDeleted(src As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
        RecordOnEventLog("Item was deleted: " + e.FullPath)
    End Sub

End Class
```